# Retag suggestion: robotic arms vs. arm CPUs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The overwhelming majority of the questions tagged as "arm" are about robotic arms. Some of them are about the ARM CPU, which is the abbreviation of "Acorn RISC Machine".

My suggestion would be, following [Shog](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/172), to do this simple differentiation also in the tagging.

I suggest to use the new tag "arm-cpu" for the questions about the CPU.

Comment: I initiated also a [question retagging edit suggestion](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13447), and a [tag wiki edit suggestion](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13446). If you agree, feel free to approve.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  I always thought the arm vs ARM distinction could have been clearer in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up.

I've now retagged all [arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arm) tagged posts relating to arm processors as [arm-cpu](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arm-cpu), added [arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arm) as a tag synonym for [robotic-arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotic-arm) and merged the [arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arm) into the [robotic-arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotic-arm) tag, so now whenever anyone tries to add `arm` as a tag it will default to [robotic-arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotic-arm) but mention that [arm-cpu](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arm-cpu) is also available.